# why justify_interval('360 days'::interval) results '1 year'

Tags: postgresql

For some reason `justify_interval(now() - '2013-02-14'::timestamptz)` produces weird results:

```
postgres=# select justify_interval(concat(365*4 +1,' days')::interval);                       -[ RECORD 1 ]----+----------------
justify_interval | 4 years 21 days
```

I checked one year:

```
postgres=# select justify_interval('365 days'::interval);
 justify_interval
------------------
 1 year 5 days
```

So I went further:

```
postgres=# select justify_interval('360 days'::interval);
 justify_interval
------------------
 1 year
(1 row)
```

This behavior is not platform specific (tried several Linuxes, 9.2, 9.3, 9.6)

Why one year is 360 days?..

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are looking for something, which PostgreSQL calls *a "symbolic" result that uses years and months, rather than just days*, which is what the `age(timestamp, timestamp)` (and `age(timestamp)`) function(s) returns.

```
select age(now(), '2013-02-14');    -- 4 years 16:41:02.571547
select age(timestamp '2013-02-14'); -- 4 years
```

The `-` operator always returns the difference in days (at most). The `justify_*()` functions (and the `*`, `/`, `<`, `>` operators) always "cut" values to an average (i.e. `1 day` is `24 hours` and `1 month` is `30 days`) despite the fact that 1 day actually can contain 23-25 hours (just think of daylight saving time zones) and 1 month can contain 28-31 days (so the result depends on the actual start and end points of the range, which creates the interval).

Answer (score 0):

[accrding to docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

> justify_interval(interval)    - Adjust interval using justify_days and
>   justify_hours, with additional sign adjustments

and further:

> justify_days(interval)    - Adjust interval so 30-day time periods
>   are represented as months

So `30*12=360`

Not expected but obviously defined in docs...