# PostgreSql: how to do where CURRENT_DATE - timestamp > (Value of years/months/days)

Tags: postgresql

May I ask, in PostgreSql, how to do

```
where CURRENT_DATE - timestamp > (Value of years/months/days).
```

Here I'd like to calculate the age of a person and verify if it is older or younger than a certain value, so I need to make the subtraction of  CURRENT_DATE and timestamp when the person was born, but then I do not know how to do, anyway one could help me?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the [`INTERVAL` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

It [can be subtracted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) from `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP`, so your best predicate will be:

```
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '18 years' > your_timestamp_column
```

Or, (when the given `INTERVAL` should be a query parameter, and) if you can only bind basic types (most likely), you can just bind f.ex. an `INTEGER` year value:

```
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (? * INTERVAL '1 year') > your_timestamp_column
```

Technically, your original logic could work too:

```
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - your_timestamp_column > INTERVAL '18 years'
```

**But** that won't use any indexes on `your_timestamp_column` & is subject to [`INTERVAL` justification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42227965/1499698).

Comment: yes, it works" INTERVAL '18 years'", thank u very much