# Why does SELECT '2019-05-03'::timestamp - '2018-05-07'::timestamp < '1 year 1 day'::INTERVAL; return FALSE in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to compare two dates and return `TRUE` if the first date is less than '1 year 1 day' from the second date.

Using 361 days instead of '1 year 1 day' returns FALSE, but this makes sense based on [why justify_interval('360 days'::interval) results '1 year'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227965/why-justify-interval360-daysinterval-results-1-year).

But when I run
`SELECT '2019-05-03'::timestamp - '2018-05-07'::timestamp < '1 year 1 day'::INTERVAL;`
I get `FALSE`, and when I run

`SELECT '2019-05-03'::timestamp - '1 year 1 day'::INTERVAL < '2018-05-07'::timestamp;`
I get `TRUE`.

Why do these return different things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find it in the docs, but this is due to the way intervals represented and compared.

Note that:

```
select timestamp '2019-05-03' - timestamp '2018-05-07' < interval '366 day';
```

gives you the expected result of `TRUE`.

To compare two intervals, Postgres first converts the intervals to [integers](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/af38498d4c9b840e0e454574519459edda3871db/src/backend/utils/adt/timestamp.c#L2340). This is done in a pretty naive way, where years are concerned:

```
/*
 *      interval_relop  - is interval1 relop interval2
 *
 * Interval comparison is based on converting interval values to a linear
 * representation expressed in the units of the time field (microseconds,
 * in the case of integer timestamps) with days assumed to be always 24 hours
 * and months assumed to be always 30 days.  To avoid overflow, we need a
 * wider-than-int64 datatype for the linear representation, so use INT128.
 */
```

So, your query is asking:

```
select 361 * 24 * 3600 * 1000000 < (1 * 12 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000000) + (1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000000);
```

Or,

```
select 31,190,400,000,000 < 31,190,400,000,000;
```

which is obviously false. ^^

Comment: What does this part mean: `24 * 86400`? Shouldn't it be just `86400` or `24 * 3600` instead? (it does not change the final result though indeed)

Comment: Yep, fixed in the answer. Thanks!